# Changing horizontal velocity XP-PEN Deco 01

Tags: touchpad, graphics-tablet

I have an XP-Pen Deco 01 and have installed Ubuntu with KDE.
My question is: Can you change the horizontal speed of the pen?
Since I have 2 monitors, the horizontal speed is twice as high as the vertical, which makes navigation via pen (which I would quite enjoy) a sub optimal experience.

I know how to fix this for touchpads via synaptics, but I do not know about an option for the graphics tablet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04. But I wrote an e-mail to xppen and they adviced me to assign a shortcut key to the shortcut "switch monitors" after selecting one monitor. Works nicely, but if you have another solution, let me hear it.